# How to get distinct date in required timezone in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

I'm looking to fetch the unique date when the user was signed up.

```
SELECT DISTINCT createdAt::date FROM user
```

My database timestamp is in UTC, so I'm getting unique dates in UTC. How do I get unique date in another timezone ( say IST ) ?

Thanks!

Comment: `(createdat at time zone 'IST')::date`?

Comment: Silly that I did not try that, thanks - that fixed it!

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comment above, trying the below query solves it.

```
SELECT DISTINCT (createdat at time zone 'Asia/Kolkata')::date FROM user
```